# How to select two elements from two different table

Tags: sql

I want to calculate the values of two elements in two table.
For example I have two following tables,

> Table A : (item_id, item_price, item_description)
>
> Table B : (item_id, item_count, item_color)

And I want to calculate, for example:

`item_price * item_count` for all that `item_id from A = item_id from B`.

How should I do this?

Comment: you need to join Table A and Table B

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT a.Item_Id AS Item, a.Item_Price * b.Item_Count AS Tot_Cost 
     FROM TableA a, TableB b 
           WHERE a.Item_Id = b.Item_Id;
```

**Equi Join:**

SQL EQUI JOIN performs a JOIN against equality or matching column(s) values of the associated tables. An equal sign (=) is used as comparison operator in the where clause to refer equality.

You may also perform EQUI JOIN by using JOIN keyword followed by ON keyword and then specifying names of the columns along with their associated tables to check equality.

***Syntax:***

```
SELECT column_list 
FROM table1, table2....
WHERE table1.column_name =
table2.column_name;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
JOIN table2
[ON (join_condition)]
```

***Further understanding refer below links.***

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Please, don't teach people that old syntax... Stick to the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax instead.

Answer (score 1):

Either specify your condition in `where`:

```
SELECT A.item_id, A.item_price * B.item_count AS calculated
FROM A, B
WHERE A.item_id = B.item_id
```

Or more clear with `join`:

```
SELECT A.item_id, A.item_price * B.item_count AS calculated
FROM A
   JOIN B ON A.item_id = B.item_id
```

Comment: Please, don't teach people that old syntax... Stick to the modern, explicit JOIN syntax only.

Comment: Thank you. I am just trying to let OP understand the logical origin of JOIN. I know it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.item_price *b.item_count AS Value from A a,B b where a.item_id=b.item_id
```

Comment: Please, don't teach people that old syntax... Stick to the modern, explicit JOIN syntax instead.

Answer (score 0):

User equi join

```
select a.item_price *b.item_count AS 'Total Amount' from A a,B b where a.item_id=b.item_id
```

Comment: Please, don't teach people that old syntax... Stick to the modern, explicit JOIN syntax only.

Answer (score 0):

Please, just use modern syntax.

```
SELECT a.item_price * b.item_count 
FROM table_a as a 
    JOIN table_b as b ON a.item_id = b.item_id
```